# Google Sheets API (Python) - What's the equivalent Google API function to Excel VBA's CurrentRegion?

Tags: python, vba, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

What's the equivalent Google API function to Excel VBA's CurrentRegion?  I have multiple tables of data in a single google sheet. At any single instance, I only want to fetch one data table.

VBA's current region provides an easy way to do this in Excel.  How may I do the same using Google API Python? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no prepared method for achieving it in Sheets API. So as a workaround, for example, how about creating such API using Web Apps with Google Apps Script?